# Simple jsp script to upload file and store in database

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I want a simple JSP script to upload a file and store it to oracle database in `blob` db format.

Please provide any suitable from google, forum or any other place.

Answer (score 1):

There you go, plenty of explanations and examples in both questions:

1. [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet)
2. [How do I move zip file to blob column in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517260/how-do-i-move-zip-file-to-blob-column-in-java)